# centralizing my and my family mails

Tags: email

I am looking for a solution to centralize my mails on one server.

My idea is to download all my mails into a central place (to my locally hosted ubuntu server) from all different public mail servers. On the locally hosted server I would like to take care of backups of my mails. All my family members would sort out all their incoming mails (delete, move them in different folders...) on the locally hosted server. Servers automatically download and delete all emails from the different public email service provider (gmail, icloud, mail.com, ...). in an ideal world it would be the best when my family want to send a mail they could choose which smtp server they would like to use for email sending and those sent mails would be stored/downloaded in our locally hosted server too. Each users on my locally hosted solution would have own "account", own structure to store all their emails in folders as they want. they can connect to this locally hosted server remotely via browser as the minimum, but would be good via smart phone to reach their emails from anywhere from the world and search easily among all their emails stored in the locally hosted solution.

Is there any similar solution available? if so, can you please share the tutorial?

Thanks,
Imre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components are all there, but integration (and making sure it doesn't lose mail) would be your job. The old sysadmins are usually very reluctant touching mail systems, and for good reason, so this is not something I'd do as a beginner project -- maybe for myself, and when it works, I pull in other people.

In short, you'd use something like *fetchmail* to retrieve the mail and feed it into a local mail server (e.g. *postfix*), which puts it into the mail directory inside a local user's home directory. From there, an IMAP server (e.g. *courier* or *dovecot*) makes it available to IMAP clients (such as *thunderbird* or a mobile app) over the network. With extra configuration, you can also teach your mail server to handle outbound mail, likely by forwarding the mail to your ISP.

All of these components will be difficult to set up though because they have lots of options. Running a mail server is not an easy task, and I'd definitely recommend against doing it on a public IP address (inside your local network, not reachable from the outside is fine).

If you want to go ahead with this, try setting up an isolated system with *postfix* first with a single user, make sure that this works (you can read test mail with *mutt* locally), then expand it with IMAP access (which would allow you to read test mail on your phone), and continue from there.

The O'Reilly book on postfix is a good reference, but assumes some familiarity with how mail on the Internet works.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. It took just 2 years to do what I dreamed to have. of course in the last 2 years I have just suspended this project. It took me 1 month to setup everything, but finally everything works great.

In a nutshell I use

I. **fetchmail** to collect all users' all mails from all different external email service providers and with pop3 they are downloaded and deleted as well from the suppliers' email servers.

II. Dovecot
I also have dovecot which provides imap interface to all my family members to access to all emails collected from all different email service providers. They can use web client or iPhone, or any other devices. Regardless where they are they always have all their emails in one place.

III. Postfix
I had to configure postfix as well for 2 purposes:

1. to move all downloaded emails by fetchmail under dovecot and make them available for the end users
2. SMTP gateway (relay) which is used from the email clients to have one standard email sending option and it is forward the emails to the external SMTP servers which will send the emails to the recipients.

There were a lot of challenges, however it works now. I can backup the emails. Everything is secured. I have as much space as my family needs. I do not have to worry on the changes on the suppliers side. I don't have to pay for extra space for the suppliers. everything is free! Except my home server and the backup solution, but I use that server for sooooo many other things: plex, nextcloud, torrent, VPN, ...